# What are the boundaries in inner product of functions

Tags: functions, inner-products

As we know the definition of an inner product is:
$$
\int_a^bf(x)^*g(x) dx
$$
int quantum physics we chose $\infty$ for a & b (negative and positive). But for a general mathematical purpose how do we choose a and b? since choose differently would cause different answer for the inner poroduct?

Comment: You do get different answers, you're right. All this means is that it isn't **the** inner product---there are many possible inner products on lots of spaces.

Comment: You add an inner product to some space. The inner product you defined is for functions defined on the whole real line. But suppose you look at functions defined on $[0,1]$, then $a=0, b=1$ makes sense.

Comment: Other inner products are more complicated yet.  For example $\int_a^b f(x)\overline{g(x)} w(x)\;dx$ for some nonnegative density function $w(x)$.  (I switched from physics conventions to mathematics conventions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more than a "different inner product" when you change the values of $a$ and $b$.

If $a=-\infty$ and $b=\infty$, the integral defines an inner product on the space of all squared integrable functions on the real line:
$$
H = \left\{f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}\mid \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f|^2<\infty\right\}
$$

If $a<b$ are two real numbers, then the underlying vector space becomes:
$$
H = \left\{f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{C}\mid \int_a^b |f|^2<\infty\right\}
$$

Choosing the values of $a$ and $b$  depends on the domain of the functions that you want to work with. For instance, if you want to consider periodic functions on $[0,2\pi]$, then $a=0$ and $b=2\pi$.

For fixed values of $a$ and $b$, as GEdgar mentioned in the [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4299634/what-are-the-boundaries-in-inner-product-of-functions#comment8954453_4299634), there are [weighted versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Lebesgue_spaces) of inner products.